# PHP query class not returing values

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am writing a query class for my php project, But i have a problem the query does not return any values from my DB.

PHP code:

```
<?php

class DatabaseConnect{

    protected $host = 'localhost';
    protected $user = 'root';
    protected $pass = 'root';
    protected $db = 'test';

    public function __construct(){

        $con = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->db) or die('Cannot Connect to DB');

        return $con;

    }
}

class ExecuteQuery{

    public $connection;
    public $result;

    public function __construct(){

        $this->connection = new DatabaseConnect();

    }

    public function getQueryAction($sql){

        $this->result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $sql);

    }

    public function setStringAction($string){

        $file = file_get_contents('queryFile.json');
        $json = json_decode($file, true);

        foreach($json['Queries'] as $this->result){

            return $this->result[$string];

        }
    }
}

$execute = new ExecuteQuery();
```

Jason file ('it will contain all the queries') :

```
{
   "Queries": [

        {"query1":"SELECT * FROM tbl_user"},
        {"query2":"SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE status=1"}

    ]
}
```

Index file:

```
<?php
require_once('query.php');
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>
    </title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<h3><?php

    $execute->getQueryAction($execute->setStringAction('query1'));

    foreach($execute->result as $item){
        echo $item['id']. ' ' . $item['user_name'] .'<br />';
    }

?></h3>
</body>
</html>
```

So what I do is create a class to process jason file extract a query and then class to run a query. Jason file as I mentioned holds all the queries, In index and in any file where I include query.php i can run all the queries like this:

```
 $execute->getQueryAction($execute->setStringAction('query name'));
```

after some debugging I realised that the code fails in getQueryAction method, I think mysqli_query dont like $this->connection.

My questions are :

Why
and how to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A constructor cannot return anything, a constructor only purpose is to create an instance of a class

```
private $con;
public function __construct(){

    $this->con = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->db) 
                 or die('Cannot Connect to DB');
}

public function get_connection(){
   return $this->con;
}
```

so in `ExecuteQuery` class you can do:

```
public function __construct(){
    $db = new DatabaseConnect();
    $this->connection = $db->get_connection();
}
```

Comment: wow ok that makes a lot of sense thank you for this now I will not make the same mistake again....!!!

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli->query` does not return results. It only returns a handle with which you could request the results. Look up `mysqli->fetch_assoc`

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $sql)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($item = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $item['id']. ' ' . $item['user_name'] .'<br />';
    }

    /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

Comment: Also: if you do a `return` inside a foreach loop, you will get the first result from the loop and not all results!

Comment: Ok i just changed `return $this->result[$string];`
to `echo $this->result[$string];`

Comment: but now it only returns the query string not the results

Comment: Please read the answer again. You need to fetch the results first!

Comment: NO i dont have to I know I can make this work by: class ExecuteQuery Extend DatabaseConnect and instead having my ExecuteQuery class __construct method remove it and in qetQueryAction instead $this->connection have $this->__construct....but this does not look good I want to do the way i have the code in the question

Comment: Fetch the results whereever you want to, but you HAVE to fetch them. The result handle will not contain them this way.

Comment: For some reasony when i use mysqli->query i get error, only mysqli_query with the underscote works not the arrow

Comment: You can allways use the non OOP method, they are same. I'll update the code sample to use that.

Comment: anyway I dont belief this is the root of the problem, still belief foreach is the way forward... when I do this:

`public function getQueryAction($sql){

        $this->result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $sql);

        if($this->result){
            echo 'I am Working';
        }else{
            echo 'I am not working';
        }

    }`

I get I am not working so it is the query that fails

Comment: You are wrong, but you may have SQL errors in addition to not fetching results. Check for errors with `echo mysqli_error();` after execution of your query.

Answer (score 0):

Thx for trying to help me guys, But I just managed to fixe it with minor changes here they are:

changed the method namd from __construct to DBcon under DatabaseConnection class,
then i did this in get getQueryAction:

> $this->result = mysqli_query($this->connection->DBcon(), $sql);

the whole class:

```
class DatabaseConnect{

    protected $host = 'localhost';
    protected $user = 'root';
    protected $pass = 'root';
    protected $db = 'test';

    public function DBcon(){

        $con = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->db) or die('Cannot Connect to DB');

        return $con;

    }
}

class ExecuteQuery{

    public $connection;
    public $result;

    public function __construct(){

        $this->connection = new DatabaseConnect();

    }

    public function getQueryAction($sql){

        $this->result = mysqli_query($this->connection->DBcon(), $sql);

    }

    public function setStringAction($string){

        $file = file_get_contents('queryFile.json');
        $json = json_decode($file, true);

        foreach($json['Queries'] as $this->result){

            return $this->result[$string];

        }
    }
}

$execute = new ExecuteQuery();
```

Now everything works perfect still not sure why the previous method (present in inital question) but this works xD

Comment: Glad you found a solution. You might want to learn a bit more about OOP though if you want to use classes in the future, which you should. ;)